# How can we prove that the rank of a matrix is a non-convex function of that matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, semidefinite-programming

How can we prove that  $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{X})= 1$ is a non-convex function of $\mathbf{X}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems pretty clear that if we take $X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $Y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, then $\operatorname{rank}(tX+(1-t)Y) = 2$ for $t\ne 0,1$.

Answer (score 1):

Rank of a matrix is not convex as shown by the above answer.  However, it is  worth noting that if the matrix is positive semidefinite, it is a quasiconcave function. The modified Jensen's inequality for quasiconcave functions is $$f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y) \geq min(f(x),f(y))$$

The proof follows from the fact that $$rank(A+B)\geq min(rank(A),rank(B)) ,  A,B \in S_n^+$$